# No performance improvement when multithreading linear regression using boost c++ libraries

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, linear-regression

I am performing calls on a method using multiple threads via boost libraries. I received quite a performance enhancement doing so. I've recently introduced linear regression calculations into the method and am having a severe per thread performance penalty.

For instance, if I run a single thread, the average method call takes 2 seconds. If I use two threads, I register twice as much CPU activity, but the average method call takes 5-6 seconds. This continues as I increase threads. There are no known race conditions or (I think) significant shared memory.

It almost seems if there is some cache or other CPU hardware feature that is being utilized by all the threads, becoming a bottleneck. But I don't know enough about CPU architecture to sure. I am running an Intel Xeon 25-2620 CPU.

Help is desperately needed.

Comment: Without seeing an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) example, any answers you get will be speculative.

Comment: We would also need to know more about your hardware.  For example, running 10 threads on a 2-core machine is going to make matters much worse in some cases.

Comment: I am running on a 12 core machine.

Comment: there are caches shared between processor cores; so if your calculations are memory-heavy, the bus between CPU and RAM can and will become a bottleneck. Especially if your threads interleave and create an unpredictable "all over the place" memory access pattern, it will look very crazy in caches and in the bus.

Comment: Pavel, this is what I'm suspecting. But I didn't expect it on this simple linear regression. I used to do a 200 term least squares fit on over 700 data points, each on a separate core, without an issue. This is only three terms on about 30 data points. I don't understand the problem.